# Angular Lazy Load Without changing route

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

Any way to load items with the Lazy load without having to enter a new route? I mean, delaying the loading of some components of the current route?

In Angular I only know one way to use Lazy Load, and it is the following. I have two modules, the main module whose components are loaded from the beginning, and a secondary module where all the components I want to load with Lazy Load, then in the main module I have several routes, all of them are components that have already loaded, except one , this route will load the secondary module with all its components only when it enters that route .. My question is, How can I load that module without having to enter that route? I mean, start loading that module at a certain time of the application, either with a user interaction or whatever, what I want to achieve with this is that the application loads and immediately some modules start loading in the background, without the user has to enter to start loading.

Comment: Can you please be more clear with what you are asking?

Comment: Excuse me and update my question, I explain myself better now.

Comment: Then why do you make that module as lazy loading module? I guess you are somewhere looking in between of non lazy loading and lazy loading if I am not wrong.

Comment: I want the first view to load fast, and the two modules at the same time will take a long time.

Comment: you might want to have a look at custom lazy loading strategies: [keyword](https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadingStrategy). Other than that im not sure why you want to use lazy loading

Comment: The reason I want to use lazy load is because it's the only one I know that approaches the solution I'm looking for.